# using Single class for different types of combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a combobox cbpaymenttype have values like(DD , CASH ,CARD)

```
    I have list view  Named as listviewcashmembers

 with items lastname(xxxx),
           firstname(xxx),
           postcode(xxx),
           ddrerefernce(xxxx),
          ddprovider(xxx)
          Monthlyamount(xxx)
          MembershipType(xxxx),
           Status (xxxx)
          Enddate (xxxx)
          paymenttype(DD , CASH , CARD)
```

I have done like this for generating  pdf when we click on the print button  and appropriate selection of Combo box(cbpaymenttype.Text)

code in main form is like  this and this  code will calling another class  also

```
      private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
                private const string DDPROVIDERMEMBERS_PATH = @"xxxxxxxxxx_{0}";

              if (cbpaymenttype.Text == "DD ")
              {
                string path = string.Format(DDMEMBERSREPORT_PATH, DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmm"));
                List<DDmembersmonthlyreport> ddmembersreportmembers = new List<DDmembersmonthlyreport>();
                if (lstviewcashmembers.Items.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (ListViewItem item in lstviewcashmembers.Items)
                    {
                        DDmembersmonthlyreport ddmembers = new DDmembersmonthlyreport();
                        ddmembers.member_Lastname = item.SubItems[1].Text;
                        ddmembers.member_Firstname = item.SubItems[2].Text;
                        ddmembers.Postcode = item.SubItems[3].Text;
                        ddmembers.ddReference = item.SubItems[4].Text;
                        ddmembers.ddprovider = item.SubItems[5].Text;
                        ddmembers.Monthlyamount = Convert.ToDecimal(item.SubItems[6].Text);
                        ddmembers.MembershipType = item.SubItems[7].Text;
                        ddmembers.Status = item.SubItems[8].Text;
                        ddmembers.Enddate = Convert.ToDateTime(item.SubItems[9].Text);
                        ddmembers.paymenttype = item.SubItems[10].Text;

                        ddmembersreportmembers.Add(ddmembers);

                    }

                    new PdfDDMembersMonthlyValueReport(ddmembersreportmembers, new Company(mf.gBaseUrl).GetSingleLineCompanyDetails(), path);
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", path);
                }


          if (cbpaymenttype.Text == "cash")
          {   

                   xxxxxxxxxx
              new PdfCashMembersMonthlyValueReport(ddmembersreportmembers, new                 Company(mf.gBaseUrl).GetSingleLineCompanyDetails(), path);
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", path);



         }
}
```

like this i have done for all options in combobox (cbpaymenttype)

I have created class like this

```
  public class DDmembersmonthlyreport
  {
    public string member_Lastname;
    public string member_Firstname;
    public string Postcode;
    public string ddReference;
    public string ddprovider;
    public decimal Monthlyamount;
    public string MembershipType;
    public string Status;
    public DateTime Enddate;
    public string paymenttype;

}
public class "PdfDDMembersMonthlyValueReport"
{
    private Document _document;
    private Table _table;
    private List<DDmembersmonthlyreport> _array;
    private string _address;

    public PdfDDMembersMonthlyValueReport(List<DDmembersmonthlyreport> array, string address, string exportpath)
    {
        _array = array;
        _address = address;

        Document ddreportdoc = CreateDocument();
        PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true);

        pdfRenderer.Document = ddreportdoc;

        if (!Directory.Exists(exportpath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(exportpath);


        pdfRenderer.RenderDocument();

        pdfRenderer.Save(String.Format(@"{0}\DD members.pdf", exportpath));

    }
    public Document CreateDocument()
    {

        _document = new Document();
        _document.Info.Title = "DD MEMBERS REPORT";
        _document.Info.Author = "xxxxx";

        DefineStyles();
        CreatePage();
        FillContent();

        return _document;

    }

    private void DefineStyles()
    {
        Style style = _document.Styles["Normal"];
        style.Font.Name = "Verdana";

        style = _document.Styles[StyleNames.Header];
        style.ParagraphFormat.AddTabStop("8cm", TabAlignment.Right);

        style = _document.Styles[StyleNames.Footer];
        style.ParagraphFormat.AddTabStop("7cm", TabAlignment.Center);

        // Create a new style called Table based on style Normal
        style = _document.Styles.AddStyle("Table", "Normal");
        style.Font.Name = "Verdana";
        style.Font.Size = 6;

        // Create a new style called Reference based on style Normal
        style = _document.Styles.AddStyle("Reference", "Normal");
        style.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = "6mm";
        style.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = "6mm";
        style.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.AddTabStop("6cm", TabAlignment.Right);


    }

    private void CreatePage()
    {
        Section section = _document.AddSection();

        // Create footer
        Paragraph paragraph = section.Footers.Primary.AddParagraph();
        paragraph.AddText(_address);
        paragraph.Format.Font.Size = 8;
        paragraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;



        paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
        paragraph.Format.SpaceBefore = "1.5cm";
        paragraph.Style = "Reference";
        paragraph.AddFormattedText("DD MEMBERS MONTHLY VALUE REPORT", TextFormat.Bold);
        paragraph.AddTab();
        paragraph.AddDateField("dd MMM yyyy");

        _table = section.AddTable();
        _table.Style = "Table";
        _table.Borders.Color = new Color(0, 0, 0);

        //Defining the columns

        Column column = _table.AddColumn("1.7cm"); //Lastname
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

        column = _table.AddColumn("1.7cm"); // first name
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        column = _table.AddColumn("1.7cm"); // postcode
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        column = _table.AddColumn("1.7cm"); // DD ref
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        column = _table.AddColumn("1.7cm"); //DD provider Name
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        column = _table.AddColumn("1.7cm"); // Monthly Amount
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        column = _table.AddColumn("1.7cm"); // mship type
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        column = _table.AddColumn("1.7cm"); // status
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        column = _table.AddColumn("1.7cm"); // Expiry date
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        column = _table.AddColumn("1.7cm"); // payment type
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;


        // Create the header of the _table
        Row row = _table.AddRow();
        row.HeadingFormat = row.Format.Font.Bold = true;
        row.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

       row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Last Name");
        row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        row.Cells[1].AddParagraph("First Name");
        row.Cells[1].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;


        row.Cells[2].AddParagraph("Post Code");
        row.Cells[2].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        row.Cells[3].AddParagraph("DD Reference");
        row.Cells[3].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        row.Cells[4].AddParagraph("DDProvider Name");
        row.Cells[4].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        row.Cells[5].AddParagraph("Monthly Amount");
        row.Cells[5].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;


        row.Cells[6].AddParagraph("Memebrship Type");
        row.Cells[6].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;


        row.Cells[7].AddParagraph("Status");
        row.Cells[7].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        row.Cells[8].AddParagraph("ExpiryDate");
        row.Cells[8].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;


        row.Cells[9].AddParagraph("payment type");
        row.Cells[9].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

    }

    private void FillContent()
    {
        foreach (var item in _array)
        {
            // Each item fills two rows
            Row row1 = _table.AddRow();
            row1.TopPadding = 1.0;
            Paragraph paragraph;

            row1.Cells[0].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            row1.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
            row1.Cells[0].AddParagraph(item.member_Lastname);

            row1.Cells[1].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
            paragraph = row1.Cells[1].AddParagraph(item.member_Firstname);


            row1.Cells[2].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
            paragraph = row1.Cells[2].AddParagraph(item.Postcode);

            row1.Cells[3].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
            paragraph = row1.Cells[3].AddParagraph(item.ddReference);



            row1.Cells[4].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
            paragraph = row1.Cells[4].AddParagraph(item.ddprovider);

            row1.Cells[5].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
            paragraph = row1.Cells[5].AddParagraph(item.Monthlyamount.ToString("F2"));


            row1.Cells[6].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
            paragraph = row1.Cells[6].AddParagraph(item.MembershipType);

            row1.Cells[7].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
            paragraph = row1.Cells[7].AddParagraph(item.Status);

            row1.Cells[8].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
            paragraph = row1.Cells[8].AddParagraph(item.Enddate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"));

            row1.Cells[9].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
            paragraph = row1.Cells[9].AddParagraph(item.paymenttype);

        }

    }
}
```

I have created this classes  for diffrent combobox options(cbpaymenttype) for printing listviewitems for selection of combobxitems

My problem is i want  to use the only single class for different types of  options in  "cbpaymenttype"

would any one pls give idea about this using single class for different type of options for 
cbpaymenttype

is it possible to pass the value of cbpaymenttype to this "ddmembers.paymenttype"

Many Thanks

Comment: would any one pls give idea about this..

Comment: why you guys are giving -1 if this question is unclear pls intimate other wise dont give -1

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand. It looks like most of the code you posted isn't relevant. Can you edit it to include just the code sample that helps reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information give, this is the best I can offer...

```
public enum PaymentType { Other, DD, Cash, Card }

public class DDmembersmonthlyreport
{
    ...
    public PaymentType paymenttype;
    // Edit
    public void UpdatePaymentType(string fromCombobox)
    {
        paymenttype = (PaymentType)Enum.Parse(typeof(PaymentType), fromCombobox);
    }
}
```

Comment: if i do like this there is no need of combobox .. but i need the value coming form combobox...